# How to see what method runs faster

Tags: ruby

How can I figure out which method is running faster? Having a hard time reading about Benchmark in Ruby docs and actually implementing it. Thanks

```
def count_between(list_of_integers, lower_bound, upper_bound)
  count = 0
  list_of_integers.each do |x|
    (x >= lower_bound && x <= upper_bound) ? count += 1 : next
  end
  count
end
```

or

```
def count_between(list_of_integers, lower_bound, upper_bound)
 count = 0
 list_of_integers.each do |x|
   count += 1 if x.between?(lower_bound, upper_bound) 
 end
 count
end
```

Comment: The [`Benchmark`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) module is not that hard to use. What is it that you don't understand about it?

Comment: Check for [Gprof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gprof).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'benchmark'

def count_between_1(list_of_integers, lower_bound, upper_bound)
  count = 0
  list_of_integers.each do |x|
    (x >= lower_bound && x <= upper_bound) ? count += 1 : next
  end
  count
end

def count_between_2(list_of_integers, lower_bound, upper_bound)
  count = 0
  list_of_integers.each do |x|
    count += 1 if x.between?(lower_bound, upper_bound)
  end
  count
end

list_of_integers = (1..100_000).to_a
lower_bound = 5
upper_bound = 80_000

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report do
    count_between_1(list_of_integers, lower_bound, upper_bound)
  end

  x.report do
    count_between_2(list_of_integers, lower_bound, upper_bound)
  end
end
```

And the results:

```
     user     system      total        real
 0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.008910)
 0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.018098)
```

So the first variant is much faster.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Want to start running these tests as I get more into refactoring.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with benchmark is that, for something that executes very quickly, you need to run the test a number of times to be confident of the result. Benchmark doesn't give you any help with that - you end up having loops inside your `report` blocks and tinkering with the execution counts which is repetitive.

The benchmark-ips gem does some of that for you. Basic usage is pretty much the same as the stdlib version:

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

#define your methods and test data here.
Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report 'count between 1' do
    count_between_1(list_of_integers, lower_bound, upper_bound)
  end

  x.report 'count between 2' do
    count_between_2(list_of_integers, lower_bound, upper_bound)
  end
end
```

Produces output like

```
 count between 1    143.377  (± 4.9%) i/s -    728.000 
 count between 2     64.489  (± 4.7%) i/s -    324.000
```

Which makes it a little easier to see whether the result is significant or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here.

```
def count_between(list_of_integers, lower_bound, upper_bound)
    count = 0
    s = Benchmark.realtime do 
        list_of_integers.each do |x|
            count += 1 if x.between?(lower_bound, upper_bound) 
        end
    end
    puts "Method took #{"%.04f" % s} seconds to complete"
    count
end
```

`Benchmark.realtime` will time the block that it encloses, and return a floating point number that indicates the number of seconds it took to exeucte the block of code (within the precision of floating point numbers and the accuracy of the system's clock).

Other methods such as Benchmark.report and Benchmark.measure will give breakdowns of user, system and real execution times, which are useful for debugging why a section of code is slower than expected.